# Is an upload (put) object to AWS S3 from web browser possible?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get, put

But is a bit of a random question and no one should ever do it this way, but is it possible to execute a put api call to amazon S3 from the web browser? Using only query params.

For instance, ignoring authentication params, I know you can do https://s3.amazonaws.com/~some bucket~

To list files in the bucket. Is there a way to upload?

Comment: Yes, the documentation describes a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have  look at [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)